# PGBrowser How to redirect on another page

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am scraping html data from a website that requires a login. I am using `PGbrowser` library.

After the login, it's redirecting to dashboard, but I want to load another page instead. I did not find a solution for redirecting.

```
require 'pgbrowser.php';
$b = new PGBrowser();
$b->useCache = true;

$page = $b->get('https://www.example.com/login.aspx');
$form = $page->form(); // Retrieve form
$form->set('Username', "username");
$form->set('Password', "password");
$page = $form->submit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just do another get:

```
$nextpage = $b->get($another_url);
```

Also you probably don't want the useCache = true line.